# YAML version of dynamic Ansible inventory file

Tags: ansible

I have dynamic inventory working with a hosts file that looks like this:

```
[tag_Name_Sonarqube]

[sonarqube:children]
tag_Name_Sonarqube
```

This is a static group of dynamic groups and is working for me.  documentation on [working with dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#static-groups-of-dynamic-groups) doesn't include a YAML example.

I would prefer to use YAML because I find the format neater, but I can't work out from the example in the [documentation on inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inventory-basics-hosts-and-groups) how this would look.

Does anybody have any examples?

Comment: There is no other format for the static inventory file. The dynamic inventory is JSON, not YAML. I'm not really sure where you're going with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth... the equivalent ansible yaml inventory of your current ini is:

```
all:
  children:
    sonarqube:
      children:
        tag_Name_Sonarqube:
```

I have absolutely no clue if this can be used in your case to create the static group of dynamic groups.